# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pandas, attributeerror

I am trying to merge 2 `csv` files. and I am taking file name with `sys.argv[n]` 
but its using filenames as strings? what I am doing wrong here ? ( using `python3` )

**Code :**

```
import sys, pandas
file1 = sys.argv[2]
file2 = sys.argv[3]
pd.read_csv(file1)
pd.read_csv(file2)
merge = file1.merge(file2, on='username')
merge.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 93, in <module>
    merge_csv()
  File "setup.py", line 65, in merge_csv
    merge = file1.merge(file2, on='username')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'merge'
```

Comment: if you assign it to the variable `file1=pd.read_csv(file1)` and `file2=pd.read_csv(file2)` , does it solve? Currently, you just read the files, but dont store it in a variable

Comment: Because you are actually passing string :D What you need to do is find you csv file using your argument which is string and simply call `read_csv()` over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are merging the string file names and not the dataframes that you have created.

The dataframes you have created using `pd.read_csv` aren't assigned to anything.

Change

```
file1 = sys.argv[2]
file2 = sys.argv[3]
pd.read_csv(file1)
pd.read_csv(file2)
```

to

```
file1 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2])
file2 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a better naming for your arguments, that will makes the debug process much easier.

lets change:

```py
file1 = sys.argv[2]
file2 = sys.argv[3]
```

into this:

```py
file1_name = sys.argv[2]
file2_name = sys.argv[3]
```

that will be clear now, that they are not file types, but just a string name of the files

now lets create the objects:

```py
file1_object = pd.read_csv(file1_name)
file2_object = pd.read_csv(file2_name)
merged_file = file1_object.merge(file2_object, on='username')
```

Comment: Good use of self-documenting variables. One thing I would mention though, using `merge` as a variable name when `merge` is already a method name could cause unintended issues

Comment: @G.Anderson yes you are right, i fixed it now, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

As @anky_91 suggests, I think this is because you aren't saving the pandas dataframe anywhere. Your merge command is reading the ARGV items.

Try:

```
foo = pd.read_csv(file1)
bar = pd.read_csv(file2)
merge = foo.merge(bar, on='username')
```